# How to write Javascript in the code behind file?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Below is the snapshot of my code that includes javascript taken from gridview's item template. It also has an image control placed.

```
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="javascript:ShowChildGrid('div<%# Eval("ID#") %>');">
                        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("ID#") %>" alt="Click" border="0" src="plus.gif" />
    </a> </ItemTemplate>
```

The JS function takes an argument as ID. Now how can i write the JS in the code behind file?

It is needed because i need to display the image based on some condition in row databound event of  gridview.

P.S.: I  am aware of Register Startup Script and Client Script but i am not sure how would they fit in to satisfy my conditions.

Comment: You might need to explain more: the databound event is a server side event/process while the javascript will only work after the page is completely rendered and sent to the browser.

Comment: Scenario: Gridview contains a cell that should display an image of plus sign (imgdiv) if a variable holds a value of 1 else should not display image. if image is displayed,i am opening a child grid from JS (ShowChildGrid). This condition is being checked in gridview (Parent) rowdataBound Event. Image visible/hidden is also done. But if image is visible, then child grid is not being displayed as the JS handling is left..Any doubts? let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the JS code for each single item of the gridview in RowDataBound-event, you could add a Hyperlink-control to your ItemTemplate and set the NavigationUrl-property of this control to the JS

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" id="lnk" ImageUrl="..."/>
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

RowDataBound-eventhandler:

```
...
if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    return;
string js = String.Format("javascript:ShowChildGrid('div{0}');", rowId);
var lnk = e.Row.FindControl("lnk") as Hyperlink;
if(lnk!=null)
{
    lnk.NavigationUrl = js;
    lnk.ImageUrl = ...;
}
```

Of course, you can also use `a` and `img` using the `runat`-Attribute

Comment: +1 even though I'm personally no fan of `var` if the Type is known  and using `a` and `img` with runat="server" always feels like a hack to me. But what you say is true, and your answer is correct.

Comment: I think the OP is not after the `rowId` but after the value of the Field `ID`. In this case the OP still needs to use  `DataBinder.Eval(e.dataItem, "ID")` to get the correct ID.

Comment: Stephan: Cannot see the changes you made in the code. Plus, my variable lnk is also coming null..Why can't my GV find the control??

Comment: Did you check the RowType? `if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) { return; }` (I just added this in my code above) Is the id of your Hyperlink "lnk"?

Comment: That's some exceptional obtrusive javascript. Can't you just tell him to change his HTML and use un-obtrusive javascript rather then use this hack?

Comment: Stephan: Yes, the id of my hyperlink is "lnk"
@Raynos: Can you tell me what change should i do here?

Answer (score 2):

Change your template and use unobtrusive javascript.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <button class="imgdiv-button" data-img-id='<%# Eval("ID#") %>'>
        <img class="imgdiv" alt="Click" border="0" src="plus.gif" />
    </button> 
</ItemTemplate>

$(".imgdiv-button").click(function() {
    ShowChildGrid($(this).data('img-id'));
});
```

Basically you want a button instead of a link (because it is a button). And you should just store that img-id in a data- attribute.